# Using list of values in the Select Case Statement

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am currently trying to hide unnecessary PivotItems in my pivot table by using select case statement.

My Select Case Statement would look like this:

ws = ActiveWorksheet

```
For Each oPI In ws.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Reference Number").PivotItems

Select Case oPI.Value
Case "Value1","Value2","Value3"
'Do Nothing
Case Else
oPI.Visible = False
End Select

Next
```

However, I want to modify the statement to do two things.

1. Use "Like" inside the Case "Value1","Value2","Value3" because Value1,2,and 3 are not exact matches for the values in the PivotItems. Value 1 for example would be 12345 while in the PivotItems it would be 12345a or 12345b, or 12345c.
2. Instead of inputting in VBA the actual values of Value1, 2, and 3, I want the Case Statement to refer to a range of Cell inside my active worksheet (Range("A1:A100") for example.

I tried many combinations already but my code does not seem to work. I don't know how to do this also with IF Statements.

Your help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi allen, you could use Scripting Dictionary for this. You store each group of variables on a different dictionary and then using the Dictionary.Exists(PivotItemName) you could do the trick.

Comment: Hey Damian. Thanks for the response. I'll try to search more about using the Scripting Dictionary. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You need the library `Scripting Runtime` And then `Dim Whatever As Scripting.Dictionary`, finally you set it like `Set Whatever = New Scripting.Dictionary` so you finally loop through all the items on the range which match your criteria to store them on the dictionary. Later you will only need to test  `If Whatever.Exists(FieldName) Then`and whatever code you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the range of values to check against into an array you loop comparing against current pivotitem. I used Instr rather than Like with wildcards (%) to see if substring present.

```
Dim arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A100").Value)
'other code
For Each oPI In ws.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Reference Number").PivotItems
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(arr(i), oPI.Value) > 0 Then
            oPI.Visible = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi @Qharr Thank you for taking the time to answer. The code works well and I can definitely use this in the future. However, is ti possible to tweak the code so it would also work on approximate matches and not simply on exact matches. For example a value of an oPI is 1234500000 but the value in range A1 is 12345 only. The code above will hide the pivot item since it is not equal to 12345 but that is not what i intended. I still need to display pivot item 1234500000.

Comment: Hi @QHarr vba now prompts me "Unable to set the visible property of the PivotItem Class. This did not happen with your previous code.

Comment: Can you provide the failing value?

Comment: I am thinking the problem is in the variable "i". It was undeclared and that's the only thing i can say about it haha. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: When I go to the vba debug screen, it highlights this line oPI.Visible = False in yellow.

Comment: still failing then?

Comment: I don't know what did i do. i think i deleted some comments. I tried the code. it worked when i added one line and modified another.     oPI.Visible = False before the For i= line and change the >0 then oPI.visible = True. However, it only shows the exact matches. My head is now messed up lol.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your time with me. I think I now get it. I used the logic from your code and came up with this and it works! Hahaha Thank you very much!

For Each oPI In ws.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Reference Number").PivotItems
    oPI.Visible = False
    For Each rng In ws.Range("A1:A100")
        If InStr(oPI.Value, rng.Value) > 0 Then
        oPI.Visible = True
    Exit For
    End If
    Next
Next

Comment: I’m guessing something is truncated when reading into array or leading 0s lost.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array formula and `Match` to find "like" matches:

```
Dim ws, oPI, r

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each oPI In ws.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Reference Number").PivotItems
    r = ws.Evaluate("=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(A1:A100 & ""*"",""" & oPI.Value & """,0),0))")
    oPI.Visible = (r = 0)
Next
```

May not work if your field values are numeric and not text.

Comment: Hi Tim! Thanks for taking a minute. Some of my field values are numeric, some are alphanumeric, and some are text. I tried your code and converted the values to text by adding (') before the numeric values but it seems none of the pivot items have been hidden.